# Is there a software program which is basically a custom dictionary for mac

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, dictionary

My wife translates legal texts from language a to b (and back).
She has her own phrases which translate to specific other phrases.

Is there a tool on the market where she can add these lists, and quickly look them up? (by just typing a word and all relevant phrases pop-up)

When I look for dictionaries, it finds software pre-filled with terms/translations we don't want. Or they can be used to spell check, which we don't need.

The default Dictionary application for Mac does allow custom dictionaries, but to make them you need to be a developer.

I've been looking into textexpander-like apps as well, but still it seems like a poor fit.

Comment: Upon rereading your question it seems you don't actually need a _dictionary_ but some sort of other software - is that right? Perhaps you could clarify with an example or scenario showing exactly what it is you need this tool to do?

Comment: it sounds like you want a Translation Memory tool.  These are commonly used by translators.  One for Mac is OmegaT.  A google search should provide others.    http://www.omegat.org/en/omegat.html

Comment: Question should maybe migrated to a language related site

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes a software tool which holds some kind of custom dictionary. Which we can fill ourselves with terms and search through. I'll edit the question

Comment: @monomeeth interesting. Great to have a search term to use.